# Sliding Side Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I need help with making a vertical nav bar that slides to the right to reveal more content.
I'm aiming towards something similar to the blue bar here: http://www.teehanlax.com/labs/. The nav bar slides out (to the right) when the side navigation bar is clicked, and slides back (to the left) when the `x` button is clicked.

my code is:

```
<!--Am I implementing the jQuery right?-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html> <head> <title>Nishad</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 

$(function() { $('#nav').click(function() 
{ var leftMargin = ($(this).css('margin-left') === '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px'; $(this).animate({ 'margin-left' : leftMargin }, 500); 
}); 
}); ​ 
</head> <body> <div id="wrapper">
<div id="nav"></div> 
<div id="content"></div> 
</div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've built the entire bar, but I don't know javascript well enough to have it slide out on the click of a button.

Comment: <!--Am I implementing the jQuery right?--><!DOCTYPE HTML>
 
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Nishad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 $(function() {
    $('#nav').click(function() {
        var leftMargin = ($(this).css('margin-left') === '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px';
        $(this).animate({ 'margin-left' : leftMargin }, 500);
    });
});
​
 
 </head>
 
 
 <body>
 
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="nav"></div>
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
 
 
 

 
 </body>
</html>

Comment: You are missing the `https:` part in your `script` tag. The full tag should be something like: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Don't know how i missed that! However, adding the https: doesn't make it function like the jsFiddle you assembled

Comment: You also need to put your JavaScript/jQuery in `script` tags as well. Sorry, missed that the first time around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the element, you can see that the website is making use of a negative value for the navigation's `margin-left`. When you click the `+`, they are setting `margin-left` to `0px`.

You can get the click effect by attaching a click event handler. The sliding effect can be done using jQuery's `animate()`. Below is an example what I just mentioned.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#nav').click(function() {
  
  var leftMargin = ($(this).css('margin-left') === '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px';
                 
  $(this).animate({ 'margin-left' : leftMargin }, 500);
   
  });
   
});
```

```css
    #wrapper {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #nav, #content {
        height: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #nav {
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: -150px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: lightgreen;
    }
    #content {
        width: 500px;
        background: lightblue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="nav"></div><div id="content"></div>
    </div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvFcS/)**